# Increase Intensity of SCNLights

Tags: scenekit, scnnode

Hello I have a SCNScene that is the basis of my game. The lighting was tricky and to get the effect I wanted I ended up duplicating three lights three times. This increased the intensity of the lights to create the affect and colors I wanted. However I know that 9 lights all casting shadows has been taking a toll on my fps. Is there any way to increase the intensity of the lights like i did by duplicating them without destroying my fps?

Thanks!

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

what type of light do you have ? Do they have non-default attenuation values ? (see `attenuationStartDistance`, `attenuationEndDistance` and `attenuationFalloffExponent`).

You can try to increase the brightness of your lights colors if that's possible (if they're aren't already 100% white for instance).

Otherwise you can use shader modifiers. The `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointLightingModel` entry point will let you customize the effect of each light.

Comment: They are all spot lights. I have not changed the attenuation values. The colors are 100% red, blue, or green. What would a shader modifier do?

Comment: with a shader modifier you can multiply the light's contribution by 3.0, simulating the effect of 3 identical lights at a same position.

Comment: And would this increase my fps

Comment: you can find an example in Apple's documentation for `SCNShaderModifierEntryPointLightingModel`. And yes it will be good for performance since you'll have less lights in the scene.

Comment: I apologies but I must insist. I have looked at the documentation and am having trouble understanding it. An example would be great. Would I be applying the code to the lights or the nodes?

Comment: It sounds like the right answer so I totally want to give it to you I just need to be able to use it

Comment: you would need to add a modifier on every geometry affected by the lights, there is no support for shader modifiers on lights. You can also have a look at `SCNMaterialProperty.intensity`. If you set the intensities of ambient, diffuse and specular to `3.0` it might achieve the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

In iOS 10 & macOS 10.12, `SCNLight` now has an `intensity: CGFloat` property which'll let you multiply the brightness of each light.  Assuming you're not using PBR/IES, `intensity` acts as a permille multiplier— `1000` = `1×`, `3000` = `3×`, `100 = 0.1×`, etc.  *(When using PBR or IES lighting, `intensity` instead controls the luminous flux of the light.)*

To triple the brightness of each `SCNLight`, simply do:

```
myLight1.intensity = 3000
```